# Reading Audio file in Java as in audioread of MATLAB

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound

`audioread` function of MATLAB returns y and Fs.

`y` is `"Audio data in the file, returned as an m-by-n matrix, where m is the number of audio samples read and n is the number of audio channels in the file."`

`Fs` is Sample Rate.

For example, when audio is `.wav` and it has 16 bits per sample, data range of y is -32768 and 32767.

I want to read a `.wav` file in Java and have same type of data as I would get in MATLAB. `AudioInputStream` has information such as sample rate, sample size in bits, frame size and frame rate but how can I get the samples?

Extra: Can I also read an `.mp3` file and transform its samples to the value range of `.wav`?

Comment: You have to call the `read` methods of `AudioInputStream` to read the PCM bytes. It is up to you to sort out the bytes. The [javasound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) tag help has lot of links.

Comment: @greg-449 ok, I did. I read the `AudioInputStream` to a byte array. But it -naturally- has a range of -128 to 127. But I need values from -32768 to 32767.

Comment: If the info for the stream says it is 16 bits per sample you have to combine two bytes to get the 16 bits.

Comment: @greg-449 okay. now considering the length of arrays, it makes sense. In python, I can use `numpy.fromstring` for this with option `dtype=np.uint16`. What is combining two bytes? Concatenating every two elements in my array? Adding them to each other?

Comment: Concatenating. The order depends upon whether the format is big-endian or little-endian.